# What is difference between EntityReference and CrmEntityReference Class

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

CrmEntityReference class extends the EntityReference Class as mentioned here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.crmentityreference(v=crm.7).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2.

But what is difference between them?

Comment: Why not simply inspect the members and methods listed there to find out what extension are added or overridden?

Answer (score 2):

`CrmEntityReference` is in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` namespace.

`EntityReference` is in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` namespace.

This hints at the difference between the two: Crm* is from [Developer Extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695792(v=crm.7).aspx), which is intended to be used for client side applications. Specifically, `CrmEntityReference` and `EntityReference` should be identical, with the difference being whether or not you used Developer Extensions when generating your early bound code.

For a closer look at the features of the Developer Extensions, have a look at [Microsoft.Xrm.Client Part 1: CrmOrganizationServiceContext and when should I use it?](http://develop1.net/public/post/MicrosoftXrmClient-Part-1.aspx):

> The Microsoft.Xrm.Client namespace comes from the assembly of the same
>   name 'microsoft.xrm.client.dll'. It is not available to plugin or
>   workflow code and is designed specifically for use in Windows .NET
>   clients or ASP.NET clients that communicate with Dynamics CRM.